# Comparing float values giving unexpected results in java

Tags: java, decimal

I was performing float value comparison..and in the below program. which is a very basic one.. has some trick in the decimal length during the comparison.
Please help me understand this.

```
class C
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Float pi = new Float(3.13999999f);
        if (pi > 3.13999999) {
             System.out.print("pi is bigger than 3. ");
        }
        else if (pi < 3.13999999){
            System.out.print("pi is less than 3. ");
        }
    }
}
```

result: pi is bigger than 3

Then I have removed last one digit (9) from all three values

```
class C
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Float pi = new Float(3.1399999f);

        if (pi > 3.1399999) {
          System.out.print("pi is bigger than 3. ");
        }
        else if (pi < 3.1399999){
          System.out.print("pi is less than 3. ");
        }
    }
}
```

Now the result is : pi is less than 3

Answer (score 2):

Of course the result is unexpected. You should never/can't do exact float comparison.

Usually, if you want to compare two float values (A and B) you do the difference A-B and you compare it with an acceptable error (let's say 0.00001).

Another way would be to use Float.compareTo(Float ) method.

```
    Float pi = new Float(3.139999f);
    int result = pi.compareTo(new Float(3.139999f));

    if (result == 0) {
        System.out.println("they are equal");
    } else {
        System.out.println("something went wrong");
    }
```

Output:

```
they are equal
```

Comment: It's worth noting why.  In java, float is a  single precision 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point. It's not meant for keeping exact decimal values, so there's always a margin of error.

If you need exact numbers or managed precision you should be using BigDecimal.